# Negative Electric Capacitance

Tags: electricity, capacitance

I know electric capacitance is always positive (otherwise it doesn't make any physical sense).

But the capacitance is related to the potential difference, which can be positive or negative, depends on who I choose to be first. Also, it is dependent on the charge, which can also have a negative sign.

So my question is, can I just take the positive value of whatever I get and not worry about the signs while doing the calculation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance) defines capacitance of parallel plates as

$$C=\frac{Q}{V},$$

where $\pm Q$ is the charge on the plates (one sign for each plate) and $V$ is the voltage between them.

In other words, **yes**, if you calculate a capacitance to be negative from, say, $Q<0$, then you can just take the magnitude and call the capacitance positive.